# DevExpress xtragrid datetime does not show hours and minutes

Tags: c#, datetime-format, xtragrid

In my datagrid I have a DateTime field which does not show the hours and minutes. Well at least it shows 00:00 but my the DateTime value can not be 00:00. I use this time format string "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm".

[image]

When I show the DateTime value inside a popup it shows the hours and minutes (and seconds) so it can't be 00:00:

[image]

How can I force the datagrid to show the hours and minutes?

This is my code:

```
namespace DXWindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : XtraForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitGrid();

        }
        BindingList<Message> gridDataList = new BindingList<Message>();
        void InitGrid()
        {
            /*gridDataList.Add(new Message("joepie de poepie test \n joep meloen hallo \n mhooooo", "username", new DateTime(2008)));
            gridDataList.Add(new Message("test message 2 \n kitkat android \n toktoktoktotktotktokt", "Pipo", new DateTime(2005)));
            gridDataList.Add(new Message("test message 2 \n kitkat android \n toktoktoktotktotktokt", "Pipo", new DateTime(2006)));
            gridDataList.Add(new Message("test message 2 \n kitkat android \n toktoktoktotktotktokt", "Pipo", new DateTime(2007)));*/
            gridControl1.DataSource = gridDataList;
            gridView1.ExpandAllGroups();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gridDataList.Add(new Message(memoEdit1.Text, "username", DateTime.Now));
            gridView1.ExpandAllGroups();
            memoEdit1.Text = "";
        }

    }
}
```

This is the autogenerated code:

```
            // colsendTime
            // 
            this.colsendTime.AppearanceCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
            this.colsendTime.AppearanceCell.Options.UseBackColor = true;
            this.colsendTime.Caption = "Verzonden op";
            this.colsendTime.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
            this.colsendTime.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
            this.colsendTime.FieldName = "sendTime";
            this.colsendTime.GroupFormat.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm";
            this.colsendTime.GroupFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
            this.colsendTime.Name = "colsendTime";
            this.colsendTime.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
            this.colsendTime.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.DateTime;
            this.colsendTime.Visible = true;
            this.colsendTime.VisibleIndex = 2;
```

Comment: What you're showing is a group row. How does it appear in the cell? Also did you set the format on a DateEditRepositoryItem or on the column itself?

Comment: I have set the GroupFormat property to `DateTime "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"` and the value is coming from a object which I bound to the datagrid. I grouped the column.

Comment: The GroupInterval property is set to default.

Comment: Please show your CustomUnboundColumnData event handling code.

Comment: I do not have an CustomUnboundColumnData Event. I just posted all my code.

Comment: Then why did you set UnboundType to DateTime? I think that's the problem, right there :)

Comment: Just fixed it thanks to you I changed the GroupInterval property to Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` values are automatically grouped as dates in XtraGrid, unless the column's `GroupInterval` property is explicitely set to `Value`.

This behavior is described in the DevExpress documentation on the [`ColumnGroupInterval` enumeration.](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGridColumnGroupIntervalEnumtopic)

Side note: don't set `UnboundType` property if you're not making any handling of `CustomUnboundColumnData`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve to display time in grid using `RepositoryItemDateEdit` and assign `VistaEditTime = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True`

E.g.

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemDateEdit oItem = New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemDateEdit();

oItem.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
oItem.EditFormat.FormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
oItem.VistaEditTime = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True
this.colsendTime.ColumnEdit = oItem
this.colsendTime.AppearanceCell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
this.colsendTime.AppearanceCell.Options.UseBackColor = true;
this.colsendTime.Caption = "Verzonden op";
this.colsendTime.Name = "colsendTime";
this.colsendTime.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
this.colsendTime.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.DateTime;
this.colsendTime.Visible = true;
this.colsendTime.VisibleIndex = 2;
```